# PhoneGap App Accept Terms and Conditions?

Tags: cordova

Is there an easy way to have someone click on ACCEPT the first time the app shows and when there are updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following Logic

in your index.html add following script

```
var version = "2.0"
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var current_version = window.localStorage.getItem("version");
    if(current_version != version){
        navigator.notification.confirm(
                 'Please accept terms and conditions',
                  onConfirm,
                 'T&C',
                 'Ok, Cancel'
        );
   }
}

function onConfirm(button) {
  if(button == 'Ok'){  }  else {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set a localStorage item that on open checks to see if it has been accepted, or possibly a version number so each time an update is pushed your logic says something like

```
if(localStorage.getItem(version) == "1.0){
  console.log("already set");
}
else {
  console.log("need to accept");
  // fire alert or confirmation box once complete set version to 1.0
}
```